# How to extract value with regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to learn how to use regex to extract values using python.

how can i extract only the 9h7a2m value from this line :

D: string-1.string2 15000 9h7a2m string3

update code:

also, how do i get the top line from this :

```
<p>D: string-1.string2 15000 9h7a2m string3.string<br/>
D: string-1.string2 15000 9h7a2m string3.string<br/>
D: string-1.string2 15000 9h7a2m string3.string</p>
<p><span id="more-1203"></span></p>
<p>D: string-1.string2 15000 9h7a2m string3.string<br/>
D: string-1.string2 15000 9h7a2m string3.string<br/>
D: string-1.string2 15000 9h7a2m string3.string<br/>
D: string-1.string2 15000 9h7a2m string3.string<br/>
```

so i can be left with only the 9h7a2m

thanks in advance.

Comment: does the string contains only 6 characters?

Comment: go check out the documentation, lots of examples there. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: good question. well, sometimes the value is more than 6 or less. i am looking for a way to get whatever is between the last 2 spaces if that's possible.

Comment: You don't need regex at all, `"D: string-1.string2 15000 9h7a2m string3".split()[-2]` = `9h7a2m`

Comment: a very nice website to try regex: http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
match = re.search(r"(?<= )\S+(?= \S+$)", subject)
if match:
    result = match.group()
```

See the match in the **[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gM4pI1/2)**.

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<= )` asserts that what precedes is a space character
- `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace chars (this is the match)
- The lookahead `(?= \S+$)` asserts that what follows is a space, any non-whitespace chars and the end of the string

Comment: FYI: added regex demo and explanation. :)

Comment: @zx81 is there any reason for using a look ahead and look behind rather than just matching `" (\S+) \S+$"`.

Comment: @mhawke Yes, I wrote it to get a direct match, the one you suggest uses a capture group that we would retrieve from Group 1. Both approaches are valid.

Comment: i will read more about it, hopefully i will get better with regex.